# What is the meaning of the cow in the intro to Young Sheldon?

Tags: analysis, credits, young-sheldon

I have watched Young Sheldon up to the latest episode. Whenever the theme song is played, Sheldon is shown moving away from the cow. Why is it like that?

Comment: The first season had a sole young Sheldon moving away from either a cow or a tumbleweed. The second and third seasons opener had the whole family moving away from a cow. Sheldon is shown in a variety of outfits.

Comment: Exactly that's right @Jeeped. I wanna know the meaning of that

Comment: It's set in Texas. Lotsa cows there. Sheldon is wearing cowboy boots. What "meaning" is a simple joke supposed to have?

Comment: Thanks @BCdotWEB, my small was actually making me think Sheldon hates cows. 
I had no idea about Texas, thanks to u.

Comment: I think along with song with lyrics such as "yesterday i moved a mountain", "I can be your hero" and "I am a mighty little man". It suggests to me that inside Sheldons head he can do anything, when in actual fact he is scared by a cow. That's how I watched it, no source, just my own brain.

Comment: I note that in the third season introduction sometimes the other family members move away from the cow.  Cows are usually harmless, but if one or more show signs of aggresson moving away from them is a good idea.  An angry cow can be very dangerous.

Comment: The cow (probably) symbolises Texas.

Comment: @DenisOluka:  It's definitely not out of character for Sheldon to not like animals, or not like farming/ranching/outside much; but it's not necessarily an explicit plot point or notable event.

Answer (score 4):

It’s a parody of the “Walker, Texas Ranger” (1993) intro. This answer is found on [IMDb trivia](https://imdb.com/title/tt6226232/trivia/?ref_=tt_ql_trv), and is pretty apparent when you watch the two. It’s just a trope: Texas cowboy hero looks off into the distance in the midst of the majestic American countryside, awestruck and pensive..

[image: Chuck Norris in Texas Ranger opening]

The addition of the cow is just a joke like others said…disrupting the “epic” moment and Sheldon’s fantasy of himself.

As the show progresses I think they just add the other family members and change the outfits as a creative choice due to the show’s success. From IMDb:

> Beginning with season 3, the opening switched from just having Sheldon walking to his spot to him walking up to the rest of his family, but dressed up differently in every episode but the first, leaving his other family members initially looking at him puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just to throw Sheldon off. He is well known to be germophobic, and have some pretty irrational fears...so the cow ruining his perfect shot and then even stepping toward him is to give the audience a smile as he uncomfortabley steps back to put slightly more distance between him and the cow

Answer (score -1):

I took it to be like the Mighty Girl "Fearless Girl" statue facing the bull on Wall Street. Like Sheldon is being a mighty little man, only it is a cow not a bull, with perhaps a nod to the statue--

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Fearless Girl was unveiled at its location in March 2017. Young Sheldon first aired with the cow in the opening credits in November 2016. It seems doubtful that the credits for this show would be referencing a work of art that had not even been unveiled yet. Can you offer any evidence that supports your idea?

Answer (score -2):

I am guessing you are talking about the end of this sequence:

At the end the family is obviously posing in a similar fashion to a monument of great american heroes. The background also would be quite suitable to the western genre.
So two soft connections to the founding days of a almost constantly great nation.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The protagonists look up, slightly to the side and are motionless like statues. They are disconnected from the viewer, clearly aspiring to something great.

Then they all turn their head, which is quite uncommon for statues, let alone monuments. So they already get their first crack.

Then the camera pans and shows an ordinary cow standing right next to them. Ruining the perfect wild-west-monumental-panorama.

Then the cow even dares to take a step towards them.

The mighty, aspiring statues back off, but only a tiny, marginal bit.

Then they resume their monumental positions again. Once more magnificent, just with a cow next to them.

Addition: Some of my example statues are of the dark chapters of American history. I am not sure if there is really a pattern there. But possibly it could also be a common trait of redneck-ish statues to be disconnected from the common folk in front of them.

Comment: I’d like this answer better if it didn’t have the rhetoric. That America is an “almost constantly great nation” is very much a matter of opinion.

Comment: The video was deleted