# What is the meaning of the Young Sheldon title sequence?

Tags: title-sequence, young-sheldon

What is the meaning of the [Young Sheldon title sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Sheldon)?

> The background shows mountains and a desert, whilst the foreground has Sheldon (usually in bowtie, checked shirt, shorts and cowboy boots) walking out, standing triumphantly, before he notices a cow and backs away from it, before resuming his triumphant look as the logo appears and pans to the sky. The title sequence was changed from Season 3 onwards to include the entire Cooper family, as well as showing Sheldon in different costumes, such as Einstein, an astronaut and a train engineer

Why it was chosen? Is it a tribute to the old series? Is there any significance for the subtle changes in the sequence (for example showing specific member in addition)?

I found a [similar question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106451/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-cow-in-young-sheldon) without any real answer.

---

Found in [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6226232/trivia/?ref_=tt_ql_trv) it's a parody on Walker, but I don't see it and don't know the reference

> The show's intro is a parody of Walker, Texas Ranger (1993)

I'm asking especially because the show itself is very funny, while the intro sequence seems redundant

Found more [differences](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6226232/trivia/?ref_=tt_ql_trv)

> At least one episode opening per season is slightly different from the usual opening of Sheldon walking up, taking a superhero stance, then moving over slightly as a cow approaches. In season one, a tumbleweed rolls by, making him jump out of the way. In season two, the camera does a 360 around him.
>
> Beginning with Season 5, the rest of the family no longer looks at him puzzled when he walks up, but the animal they move away from changes from a cow to a bull.

Comment: "Meaning" in what particular way? It's to précis the aspects of Sheldon's character that we already know as an adult, from watching TBBT for 12 years.

Comment: @Tetsujin why sometimes there are some family members, the sequence looks the same but there are always small changes

Comment: "Why?" is not a question that cam be productively answered. Because that's what they chose to do for the opening.

Comment: The general idea is that this series takes place in Texas & so there is an element of 'the wild west' or the Great [American] Frontier. This coupled with the cowboy boots & cow with Sheldons geeky everyday ware, helps to blend the contemporary nerdy science/sci-fi aspects to what might be scene as a more 'primitive' and/or self discovery element. As for other openings, not sure why the changes since I haven't really watched since season one, but I would guess that some of it is homage to TBBT and/or special episodes/season arcs where his family becomes more important to his own character devop

Comment: @Flater "Why" is perfectly acceptable question when looking at an opening theme. Visual themes and music are important in establishing the series tone, where and when it might be set, and if it may relate to something specific (like another series, EPs favorite LP cover, Film, ect). user7294900 even gave suggestions as what kind of REFERENCES he's looking for.

Comment: It certainly has nothing to do with the East TX site of the story.. Maybe the director just likes mountains and desert scenes. Pine trees 100 ft tall would be more characteristic of the story site.

Comment: I'm not seeing a lot of "Walker, Texas Ranger' parody in the opening sequence. They look entirely dissimilar; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj_HKjM1ILY

Comment: [Young Sheldon: Why There's A Cow In The Opening Sequence](https://screenrant.com/young-sheldon-opening-credits-cow-significance-meaning-explained/) - Not a great article. Long on speculation and very very short on actual evidence

Comment: Replaced the link for the third video from Season 6 due to the YouTube account that created the original third video being deleted and thus the video itself no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

The opening sequence series one and two has Sheldon situated in his local environment, Texas, (the micro) [note: East or West is immaterial because it represents how the world sees Texas], but looking out across the universe thinking of much bigger things (the macro). Sheldon's family joins in supporting him from series 3 onwards, they realise his gift is worth supporting. The cow represents his local community, that he has to get along with in order to survive, he has to be aware of it and move over a little, so as not to anger it, but doesn't distract much, his quest to learn all things.

Comment: Nice answer, is it your opinion or is there a reference? why the different intros have changes which seem accidental? It seems redundant

Answer (score 1):

Here's the reasoning behind the "Young Sheldon" intro.
The bold, western background is a universal depiction of Texas as most of the world has come to know it from multiple western movies.
Sheldon's family are proud Texans (as anyone that has spent any time in Texas knows of the enormous pride found in it's inhabitants). The family standing proud and looking up and ahead is the spirit of pioneers and independent thinkers.
Sheldon's entrance walk toward the family shows cowboy boots moving over the rugged terrain, leading the audience to expect a rough and tough cowboy bravely marching toward his destiny. Yet, the camera pulls up to show a nerdy young Sheldon dressed inappropriately like a normal kid or some character in his scientific, academic world. Sheldon stands proud and confident. He knows who he is and so does his supportive family.
The cow moving a step toward the family, which slightly startles the family just enough to move an equal step is suggesting that although this family is rooted strongly in historical Texas agricultural traditions and culture, they're not Cowboys, but not frightened of it and moving ever so slightly away from the stereotypical ideas of Texans.
Then the camera tilts up toward a sunny, summer sky with billowy, dreamy clouds which represents an optimistic, promising perspective for Young Sheldon and his family's outlook.

Comment: Nice answer, is it your opinion or is there a reference? why the different intros have changes which seem accidental?